# How to add constraints and conditions in JAVA?

Tags: java, cmd

So I deleted my post a while ago and I'm gonna show to you my work so far. Basically, I'm a newbie and I hope you can help me with this one because I'm struggling to figure what to do next.

```
public class Display{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //int testcase = input.nextInt();
        int n = 0, even = 0;

        //while(input.hasNext()){
        n = input.nextInt();
        while(n != 1){
            if(n%2 == 0){
                //even++ then n/=2
                even++;
            }
            else{
                //n = 3n+1
            }
            //sequence ctr++
        }
        System.out.println(even);
        //output
    }
}
```

So my professor asked us to do a 3n+1 problem/Collatz Conjecture and here are some of the conditions.

For an input N, the cycle length of N is the number of numbers generated up to and including the 1. In the example above, the cycle length of 22 is 16. Given a number N, you are to determine the absolute difference between the cycle length of N and the number of even numbers generated from the sequence starting N.

Constraints:

```
1 <= T <= 100000
1 <= N <= 1000000
```

Input Format
The first line of input contains integer T indicating the number of test cases. T lines follow. Each T line contains a number N.
Output Format
For each value of N, display the absolute difference between the cycle length of N and the number of even numbers generated from the sequence starting N.
Sample Input

```
4
10
34
22
18237
```

Sample Output

```
2
4
5
55
```

Explanation
For test case N = 10; the sequence generated is 10 - 5 - 16 - 8 - 4 - 2 - 1 with cycle length of 7. There are 5 even numbers on the sequence which are 10, 16, 8, 4 and 2. The answer is 7 - 5 =2.

Comment: If you are a newbie and have a professor, do you have fellow students to collaborate with?  It might be easier and faster.

Comment: please don't deface your post.

Comment: But someone can delete this post for me?

Comment: Stop it with the edits @geomxy. 1) You won't win 2) it's the shortest route to being suspended. If you don't want to be associated with it any more, ask for a disassocation. It won't be deleted because there is a good answer.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-ccwiki

Comment: @Geomxy You will be removed as the "asker" of the question.

Answer (score 2):

So what are you missing in your code? Take a look at it. You need to change `n` at each iteration. Depending on your requierment this needs to be done differently for even and odd numbers. This is what you are missing in your whole loop. On the other hand you keep track of the amount of even numbers that do occur, but what you forgot is to keep track of the total amount of operations invoked in your loop.

Heres how your code could look like with some comments as explenation.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = 0; 
    int even = 0; 
    // You need a variable to count each iteration. One iteration is one mathematical operation on the number. So after each iteration a new number is generated
    // We start with 1 since we have a number that we input.
    int count = 1;  
    System.out.println("Please input a number");
    n = input.nextInt(); 
    while(n != 1){ 
        if(n%2 == 0){ 
            // The first thing missing. You didn´t change n the condition is ok
            // By calling n/2 you change n as your requirement says. Devide n by two if it is even
            n/=2; // We assign and divide n by two in one step by using /=
            ++even; 
        }
        else{
            // A small syntax mistake. you code said n = 3n+1
            // But 3n isn´t known to the java compiler and you would need to tell java what mathematical operation you would like to have here. 
            // That´s where 3*n is valid.
            n = 3*n+1; 
        }
        // The next thing is here. you said you would need to have the total
        // amount of numbers after each iteration. so you just need to 
        // increase it buy one after each iteration. One iteration would be one mathematical operation on your number. 
        ++count; 
        System.out.println("n is now " + n); 
    }
    System.out.println("we had " + even + " even numbers");
    System.out.println("we had " + count + " total numbers");
    // Now that you keep track of both, the total amount of numbers and the even numbers you would need to simply subtract them from each other to get your result.
    System.out.println("Resulting in total - even as:" + (count-even)); // Just subtract and print out your expected Output.
}
```

Comment: @Geomxy as i described you only had to change the value of your number `n` and keep track of the amount of iterations in your loop. The rest would have worked.

Comment: How? Sorry if I really don't understand. ; - ;

Comment: I´ll edit my answer and tell you what you have been missing :)

Comment: Btw. We need to run this using cmd prompt only.

Comment: Do you get the number as a parameter when you invoke the programm or should you input it manually?

Comment: It didn't give the expected output. When I input 4
10
34
22 18237 it didn't give 2 4 5 55

Comment: Another question you have 5 inputs. Do you input them seperatly? and how does it come that it generates 4 output numbers?

Comment: My bad. It was 5 inputs then it generates 4 output numbers. ^^v

Comment: At which point doesn´t the output match? i am getting the oupput `1 2 4 5 55` for these specific inputs

Comment: How? Did you insert them one by one?

Comment: Yes. Might is ask if you input the numbers in the commandline as `java programmname 4 10 34 22 18237`?